# SQL Server - DELETE from subquery/derived table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way I can turn the below `SELECT` statement into a `DELETE`?

I would like to delete the corresponding returned records from the `[ETL].[Stage_Claims]` table.

Since I used derived tables I can't reference the `Stage_Claims` table.

To summarize, the 2 physical tables used in the below query have identical structures. Only difference is `DUPS_Claims` is a subset of `Stage_Claims`.

`DUPS_Claims` contains duplicate records found in `Stage_Claims`. If a record exists 3 times in `Stage_Claims`, we will have that record 3 times in `DUPS_Claims` as well.

`Stage_Claims` contains all records including the duplicate records in `DUPS_Claims`.

I would like to remove the duplicate records from `Stage_Claims` leaving only 1 unique record for every duplicated record.

`Stage_Claims` has just short of 1 million rows so I do not want to use Row_Number / Partition on the entire table as it takes over 2 minutes to run.

The below query I have runs in about 15 seconds and successfully identifies only the duplicate records  (not including the original unique record we want to keep) but I have not been able to figure out how to delete the records that are returned from SC.

Is it possible or should I just take a different approach?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SC.ID ORDER BY SC.id
            )
        ,SC.*
    FROM [ETL].[Stage_Claims] SC
    WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM (
                SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id
                        )
                    ,ID
                FROM [ETL].[DUPS_Claims]
                ) AS t1
            WHERE RN > 1
            )
    ) AS t2
WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert your select statement into a CTE, and `DELETE FROM` the CTE, as in:

```
;WITH del AS
(
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SC.ID ORDER BY SC.id
            )
        ,SC.*
    FROM [ETL].[Stage_Claims] SC
    WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT ID
            FROM (
                SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id
                        )
                    ,ID
                FROM [ETL].[DUPS_Claims]
                ) AS t1
            WHERE RN > 1
            )
    ) AS t2
WHERE RN > 1
)
DELETE FROM del;
```

Standard warning: You should test this in a non-production environment.

You can simplify your query quite a bit, and likely get better performance by using the below query, which does not make use of the intermediate table, `DUPS_Claims`, since it is absolutely unnecessary:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT sc.ID
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sc.ID ORDER BY sc.ID)
    FROM ETL.Stage_Claims sc
)
DELETE
FROM cte 
WHERE rn > 1;
```

I created a non-clustered, non-unique index on both tables, then looked at the execution plans for both variations.

The first variant:

[image]

The second variant:

[image]

The first variant scans the index twice, whereas the second variant clearly only needs to scan the index a single time, and doesn't require a relatively expensive merge join in my somewhat contrived example.  My sample `ETL.Stage_Claims` table contains 89 unique `ID` values, each duplicated 89 times, for a total of 7921 rows.

In case CTEs aren't your thing, you can use this approach to delete from a derived table, instead:

```
DELETE c
FROM (
    SELECT sc.ID
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sc.ID ORDER BY sc.ID)
    FROM ETL.Stage_Claims sc
) c
WHERE rn > 1;
```

The query plan for the above `DELETE` from the derived table:

[image]

Comment: @Max Vernon Worked perfectly (and much better performance), thanks!